# multiple user on sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-administration

It might be very basic question for you friends, but how to allow multiple users on SQL Server installed on remote windows server 2012 machine.?

right now only two user can work at the same time if third one comes one of two who are active has to allow and get out himself.

we are building new server which will allow multiple user to work on the same time.

My question is once we install SQL server on windows server machine what configuration needs to be done to achieve our goal(Multiple user can work on same time) on server machine as well as what configuration needs to be done on computers of people who will be logging into it.

do we need same number of instance similar to how many people will be working on it? if yes it means that many number of same database on the server and more space will be occupied right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'user connections', 777;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Replace 777 with your limit of connections.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your quick reply, but can you please explain security concern with this, it has to be secure since we will be dealing with financial information. I believe 777 will aloow anybody with sql server login and password, m i right?

Comment: It's better to use windows authentication if possible. But sql server authentication with strong passwords is also ok. Anyway I suggest you to restrict your users in rights. Best practice is giving access only to specific stored procedures.

Comment: well, it would be something like one person will be accessing same database for MS DYnamics CRM , i will be using it for SSRS and other person will be using it for migration. and I am not experts on administation side of sql server so kind of fully confuse right now. we really don't want someone to work from local machine on server via logging into it. we want everyone to login to server via remote desktop connection and then work. I also belive we have to crete that many instances right?